# how do i get math.random to not do every else if

Tags: javascript, math, discord.js

I tried to make a var for math.random that ONLY SENDS ONCE for a discord bot specifically, if it runs fine in the terminal that's awesome, but it seems to be lost in translation on it's way to discord if that's the case.

```
var random = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

then tried it with

```
if (random == 1){
        message.channel.send("you got 9:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!")}
    else if (random == 2) {
        message.channel.send("you got 0:cookie:! Try Again?")}
        //repeat this im not typing all this out sorry
    else if (random == 3) {
        message.channel.send("you got 3:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!")}
    else if (random == 4) {
        message.channel.send("you got 0:cookie:! Try Again?")}
    else if (random == 5) {
        message.channel.send("you got 9:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!")}
    else if (random == 6) {
        message.channel.send("you got 5:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!")}
    else if (random == 7) {
        message.channel.send("you got 6:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!")}
    else if (random == 8) {
        message.channel.send("you got 0:cookie:! Try Again?")}
    else if (random == 9){
        message.channel.send("you got 2:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!")}
    else if (random == 10) {
        message.channel.send("you got 0:cookie:! Try Again?")}
    else{
        message.channel.send("Amonger")}
```

and it didn't work, I DO know that it's the math.random causing it, and I need to know how to setup this monstrosity, I'm not an amazing spectacular coder, so if I don't understand something, don't be surprised.

The output is always you got 9:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!, mind you this is being sent into a discord channel(:cookie: is just a cookie emoji in Discord). The output should select a random one out of these, specifically whatever number the variable random selected, I dunno if the variable rolls once or multiple times, if it rolls at all.

and older version that I can't remember the code of just sent ALL the else if statements when the prefix $cookie was used in chat as a command, as the $cookie is the command that activates this. if it's any use the code above it is

````
   name: 'cookie',
   description: "RNG Cookie Command",
   execute(message, args){```

// which is sent to the main code with 

   ```if(command === 'cookie'){
       client.commands.get('cookie').execute(message, args); ```

// (using the three ` doesn't seem to remove these from the code section of the post so act as if the two slashes aren't aren't part of the code)EDIT: I'm thinking it might have to do with the message.channel.send but I don't know
````

Comment: It is not the problem with `math.random `

Comment: Can you paste the output generated by this code?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a problem description. Explain what you wanted to do, what code you wrote to do that, show the result of that code, and talk about how that's different from what you expected and what you already tried in terms of debugging and (re)searching for solutions. `var random = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);` does exactly what the code says it'll do, so if you want to show it's not doing that: _show_ it's not doing that by showing a [mcve] in your post

Comment: Really I am getting an output different outputs every time ! I think everything is working fine

Comment: I can't really show a reproducible version considering this is an entire bot and I've only shown you this section of it's code

Comment: @Skyitande Checkout this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atq6csd8/) it will help you to improve your code and change from if else to switch and better understanding too ! .... Also your code is absolutely correct it has no errors ... I added a console logging in this fiddle too so you can see what is happening .........

Comment: @Sanmmet This is awesome, I have no clue how switches work or really half the stuff in my code works either, like I said, not a big coding person, mostly making this bot for personal value

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object to store your responses where the keys are the possible random numbers and the values are the message you want to send.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'cookie',
  description: 'RNG Cookie Command',
  execute(message, args) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    let responses = {
      1: `you got 9:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!`,
      2: `you got 0:cookie:! Try Again?`,
      3: `you got 3:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!`,
      4: `you got 0:cookie:! Try Again?`,
      5: `you got 9:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!`,
      6: `you got 5:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!`,
      7: `you got 6:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!`,
      8: `you got 0:cookie:! Try Again?`,
      9: `you got 2:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!`,
      10: `you got 0:cookie:! Try Again?`,
    };
    message.channel.send(responses[random] || 'Amonger');
  },
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I run this in node, it seems to run as expected. I get a new message every time with a random number of cookies. I did set your minimum to 0 so that it could perform the way it seems you'd expect it too.

```
const randomCookie = () => {
    const random = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 0);
    const message = `you got  ${random}:cookie:! They're sweet and yummy!`;
    
    if(random === 0) return "you got 0:cookie:! Try Again?";
    
    return message;
};
```

I believe you can just send your message as

```
message.channel.send(randomCookie());
```

I'm not sure what your requirement to send "Amonger" is. This setup will always return a number between 0 and 10.

Comment: lol Amonger is just what it would send if nothing in the list worked, it never really worked as intended

Comment: $cookie was the command it would use, so I would go in chat and put $cookie, then the bot would see that and use the client.commands.get

Comment: It sounds like you are making a discord bot which is in my list of things to do but I haven't done yet. I can't help you with command handling but I know there are some great YouTube videos on the subject. If you're looking to return a message in response though, this function should do the trick for that part of the code.

Comment: I've looked over discord bot videos, but this is so specific that I'm not surprised there isn't a video for it